# Which files display categories in the wordpress backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We migrated all the files from one domain to another. It has created issues with the wordpress default post's categories. It does not display any category in the backend although they exist in wordpress tables. When we add new category, it does not get displayed in admin panel. The screen shot is as dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39933074/category-error.png. I think the issue is due to some files are missing while migrating the files.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue and also please let me know which files contains the code which retrieves categories in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Do some basic WordPress troubleshooting first:

1. Deactivate all your plugins
2. Use a default theme (i.e. Twenty Thirteen)
3. Try again

If that doesn't fix your problem, reinstall WordPress via your dashboard (-> Updates).